# Magento return_url param in product_addtocart_form redirects but loses success messages

Tags: php, magento, redirect, product, message

In Magento CE (ver. 1.6.2.0 ) I have managed to create a category url variable on the individual product pages, which contains the url of the category page the product belongs to.

I set this variable as the return_url parameter in the product_addtocart_form and this successfully redirects to the correct page after the product is added to the cart.

However, after the redirect there are no success messages that appear to tell the customer the product was added to the basket successfully.

I was wondering if anyone else has had an issue like this before and managed to solve it or if anyone has any ideas at all?

My code edit in app/design/frontend/THEMENAME/THEMENAME/template/catalog/product/view.phtml inside  ...  is below to set the category url parameter.

```
<?php
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$_category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
$currentCategoryId = $_category->getId();
$categoryURL = Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($currentCategoryId)->getUrl();
?>
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="<?php echo $categoryURL; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 1):

It will not display because it will flush after the first display which will be on your cart page.

You could recreate the message before redirecting in your cart template/controller using

> Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addSuccess("Your cart has been updated successfully!");